# Retrieve related field detail instead of id

Tags: python, django

I have a model like this>

```
class Orders(models.Model):
 ....
 status = models.ForeignKey('Status')

class Status(models.Model):
 status_name = models.CharField(max_length=CHARFIELD_MAX_LEN)
```

And in my views I make a query like this>

```
all_orders = Orders.objects.all()
resp = serializers.serialize('json', all_orders)
```

But what I need is to get the status name instead of the status id stored in the orders table, how can that be done?

Comment: What's `serializers.serialize`?

Comment: django's [serializers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/serialization/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using [natural keys.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/serialization/#serialization-of-natural-keys) You need to define `natural_key()` method in `Status` model and pass `use_natural_foreign_keys=True`.

```
class Orders(models.Model):
   ....
   status = models.ForeignKey('Status')

class Status(models.Model):
    status_name = models.CharField(max_length=CHARFIELD_MAX_LEN)
    #def natural_key(self):
        return (self.status_name,)
```

Then to serialize objects

```
all_orders = Orders.objects.all()
resp = serializers.serialize('json', all_orders, use_natural_foreign_keys=True)
```

Comment: That's it, thank you. There was a minor issue though, **use_natural_foreign_keys** if for django 1.7 only, prior versions use **use_natural_keys**.

Answer (score 0):

according to [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values):

```
all_orders= Orders.objects.all().values_list('status__status_name')
```

It will get the list of status name